# Can someone explain this statement (foreign key) of a table

Tags: database, db2, foreign-keys

```
CREATE TABLE genres 
(
    genre_id  INT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY NOT NULL,
    genre     VARCHAR(255) N[enter image description here][1]OT NULL, 
    parent_id INT NULL, 

    -- Will be thankful to you for explaining the 3 lines below
    PRIMARY KEY (genre_id),

    CONSTRAINT fk_parent 
        FOREIGN KEY(parent_id) REFERENCES genres(genre_id)
);
```

Comment: Explain what? What exactly don't you understand?

Comment: @– B001ᛦ PRIMARY KEY(genre_id), CONSTRAINT fk_parent FOREIGN KEY(parent_id) REFERENCES genres(genre_id) );

Comment: Take a look at [constraint](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/creating-table-advance/constraint.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PRIMARY KEY(genre_id) - means that at most one row in the table GENRES can have a specific value. In other words, for every row in the table, the value in GENRE_ID column will be unique. Additionally the value in the column cannot be null, and that value serves to identify the row uniquely without needing any other value to identify the row. The DDL shows that the database will generate the value for the GENRE_ID column by default.

The "CONSTRAINT fk_parent FOREIGN KEY(parent_id) REFERENCES genres(genre_id) )" means that the database-manger
will enforce that if column PARENT_ID is not null then the value in this column must be an existing value in a row in the GENRES table. Another way of thinking about this is that the database-manager is asked to maintain a parent-child relationship, so a genre may have sub-genres (i.e. a genre may have child genres). So the database manager would not let you specify that a particular genre was a sub-genre of a non-existent parent genre.

The database manager might also enforce the relationship is valid over time, for example it might prevent a delete or update action if that delete would produce orphan rows (i.e. child rows with no parent row) , or it may set such parent_id values to null, depending on the DDL and Db2-version/platform.

Answer (score 0):

Answer:Self Referencing Foriegn Key

https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/questions-about-primary-and-foreign-keys-you-were-too-shy-to-ask/